# if $P(P(x)))=P(x)^{16}+x^{48}+Q(x)$,Find the smallest possible degree of $Q$

Tags: polynomials

let $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are two polynomials such that
$$P(P(x)))=P(x)^{16}+x^{48}+Q(x)$$
Find the smallest possible degree of $Q$

My idea: let $$P(x)=a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$$
$$Q(x)=b_{m}x^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_{0}$$
then
$$P(P(x))=a_{n}[a_{n}x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}]^n+\cdots$$
so
$$deg(P(P(x))=n^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow deg(P(x)^{16})=16n$$
so we must have
$$n^2=16n\Longrightarrow n=16$$
(because the degree of the left side must be equal to the degree of the right, assuming $m < 48$).

Comment: You need to exclude the possibility that $\deg(P(P(x)) = 48$ (obvious) or $\deg(Q(x))$. Note that $Q(x) = P(P(x))-P(x)^{16}- x^{48}$ will always be a solution. Sufficient to say "Let $P(x) = x$, then $Q(x) = -x^{48} -x^{16} +x^2$ satisfies the condition and is a polynomial of degree 48. Henceforth, let $\deg(Q(x)) < 48$."

Comment: then? Thank you

Comment: @CalvinLin Do you suppose that it is possible to have $\deg(Q(x)) = 0$, i.e. there exists $P(x)$ s.t. $P(P(x)) = P(x)^16 + x^{48}$? Since there are no restraints on the coefficients of $P(x)$ I would suppose it is true, but I'm not very knowledgable in this area.

Comment: @user92774 It is possible, but not very likely. $P$ is not a monomial, hence the iterated P and P power are quite different from each other.

Comment: So I guess the "degree on LHS = degree on RHS" argument isn't very helpful in this case other than just getting a upper bound.

Comment: Are complex coefficients allowed?  If so, $P(x)=ax^3$ where $a^{16}=-1$ gives a $Q(x)$ of degree $9$.

Comment: @Jared I like that interpretation, but generally these questions are for real polynomials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty standard approaches with polynomials, done by considering degrees and coefficients. Just have to push through the mess.

Let $P(x) = x$, then $Q(x) = -x^{48} -x^{16} +x^2$ satisfies the condition and is a polynomial of degree 48. Henceforth, let $\deg(Q(x)) < 48$. Furthermore, if $P(x)=P$ is a constant polynomial, then $Q(x)$ has degree 48. So we have $ \deg(P(x)) \geq 1$.
Also, observe that since 48 is not a square, hence $ \deg( P(P(x) ) )\neq 48$. Also, $P(x)^{16} + x^{48}$ has degree at least 48.

Thus, we need only concern ourselves with  $ \deg P(x) = 16 $ as claimed.

Consider the leading coefficient of $P$. By considering the coefficient of $x^{256}$, we have $a_{16} a_{16}^{16} = a_{16}^{16}$. Hence $a_{16} = 1$.

Let $k<16$ be largest integer such that $a_k$ is a non-zero coefficient. Then, we have

$$P(P(x) ) = P(x) ^{16} + a_k P(x) ^ k + \ldots = P(x)^{16} + x^{48} + Q(x) \\
\Rightarrow a_k P(x) ^ k + \ldots = x^{48} + Q(x)$$

Now, if $k \geq 4$, the LHS has degree $16k > 48$, which forces $\deg( Q(x) ) > 48$. Hence ignore.
If $ k \leq 2$, then the LHS has degree $16k < 48$, which forces $\deg( Q(x) ) = 48$. Hence ignore.
Thus $k = 3$.

Let $P(x) = x^{16} + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0.$ We have

$$ a_3 (x^{16} + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0)^3 + a_2 (x^{16} + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0)^2 + a_1(x^{16} + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0) + a_0 \\ = x^{48} + Q(x). $$

In order for $\deg(Q(x)) < 48$, the terms $x^{48}$ must cancel out, which gives us $a_3 = 1$.

Now, observe that the LHS has a term $(x^{16})^2 x^3$ with a non-zero coefficient. Hence $\deg (Q(x)) \geq 35$.

Finally, take $P(x) = x^{16} + x^3$ and $Q(x)= 3x^{35} + 3x^{22} + 9$ is a polynomial of degree 35. Hence we are done. [Of course, $P(x) = x^{16} + x^3 + $ any quadratic will also suffice.]

Comment: Oh,Nice answer! Thank you

Comment: In $$ a_3 (x^{16} + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0)^3 + a_2 (x^{16} + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0)^2 + a_1(x^{16} + a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0) + a_0 \\ = x^{48} + Q(x). $$, why you haven't substituted $(P(x))^{16}$? am I missing some thing?

Comment: @Alt I did substitute in $P(x)$. But remember that I already cancelled out $P(x) ^{16}$ in the previous line, which was a great way of dealing with a 'strange' term.

Comment: Yes sure, very nice!